# PGFplot: read in table and subtract columns (Error)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

I try to do some simple math with columns I read in but as soon as I try to subtract the columns from each other, ie without subtraction it seems to work, I get the error message:

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '- '). ... (x=0) Y}, col sep=comma] {clipped3.csv};
```

Unfortunately, it seems to work with my mini example but if I use the csv file I would like to process it doesn't work any more, has one a clue?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
/vdda! (x=0) X,/vdda! (x=0) Y,/input (x=0) Y
3.34529984540E-05,1.2,0.600843092
3.35459699742E-05,1.2,0.600842796
3.36089849871E-05,1.2,0.600842484
3.36720000000E-05,1.2,0.600842102
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=1.3]
\addplot 
table [x expr=\thisrow{/vdda! (x=0) X}, y expr=\thisrow{/vdda! (x=0) Y} - \thisrow{/input (x=0) Y}, col sep=comma] {clipped3.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[clipped3.csv](http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/GdITXOvR/file.html)

Comment: A 4.62MB csv file? That's a lot of information... Anyway, have you thoroughly checked your file? It seems `pgfplots` found something unexpected in your data. Remember that it must be consistent and regular, even a character out of place can generate errors.

Comment: Clip your data in half, and try them. The one with the error clip that into another half etc. so you can find the culprit.

Comment: Did one of the tricks of Alenanno or percusse help, because the CSV file is no longer available at the provided link.